# How to begin an email about recent meetings

Tags: word-choice

I was involved in a couple of meetings recently which the company CEO attended. I wanted wanted to give some feedback on the meetings; but am unsure how best to begin the email...

I thought of the following but just doesn't sound right...

"following on from the recent meetings..."

Is there a better way of beginning this sentence?

Comment: I would say, "As a follow-on to the recent meetings..." I also would have asked this question on [ell.se], but perhaps you weren't aware of that community yet.

Comment: Thanks J.R. I'm new to this forum, so thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously personal preference is a big factor here.  I would suggest you keep it simple:

"I would like to provide some feedback regarding our meeting on [date] concerning [topic]" or

"I have some feedback regarding our meeting on [date] concerning [topic]" or

"Regarding our meeting on [date] concerning [topic] I want to provide the following feedback:"

I would suggest you avoid adding in too many unnecessary words solely to try to impress the CEO.  One thing I've found all CEOs to have in common is a lack of time, so get to the point of the email as quickly as possible without being rude or abrupt.

Finally when I've had difficulty with an email I walk through a scenario of "if I called the CEO right now to talk about this instead of sending an email, what would I say?"  I like to have emails that closely mimic an actual conversation - in person or on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything wrong with your suggestion, however just to give you another option:

> Regarding the meetings about  that took place on , I would like to...